# remove duplicates from INNER JOIN two tables SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following:

```
SELECT id, name, job_id, job_type, job_name, updated_at
FROM
(SELECT service.id,service.service_name FROM services as service
  INNER JOIN positions p ON service.id = p.service_id
) As Tab1
 INNER JOIN
 (SELECT job.job_id, job.job_type, job.job_name, job.updated_at
  FROM jobs as job
  INNER JOIN positions p ON job.id = p.job_id
 ) AS Tab2
```

How can i remove duplicates created by **INNER JOIN** i tired with **DISTINCT** but its not working correct.

**positions** Table has only two rows this table is my middle table:

```
INSERT INTO `positions` (`id`, `service_id`, `job_id`) VALUES
(1, 440, 25),
(2, 439, 63);
```

Comment: DISTINCT is most propably working correct. Do you really get duplicated _rows_?

Comment: Show us some sample result, and what you want instead. (As formatted text, no images.)

Comment: i get duplicate mixed rows from Inner Join not completely duplicates

Comment: Make it easy and possible to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: You probably need a group by on the fields to be unique and an aggregate function on the fields with the unwanted distinct values

Comment: In the table positions i have only 2 entreis but the SQL returns me 4 mixing and combining from the 2 selects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a sbselect of the second inner join, and the join with the subselect has no join cirteria

```
SELECT id, name, job_id, job_type, job_name, updated_at
FROM
(SELECT service.id,service.service_name FROM services as service
  INNER JOIN positions p ON service.id = p.service_id
) As Tab1
 INNER JOIN -- this join has no join cirteria
 (SELECT job.job_id, job.job_type, job.job_name, job.updated_at
  FROM jobs as job
  INNER JOIN positions p ON job.id = p.job_id
 ) AS Tab2
```

You don't need the subselects in the first place, try somthing like

```
SELECT service.id, service.name, job_id, job_type, job_name, updated_at
FROM
 services as service
 INNER JOIN positions p ON service.id = p.service_id
 INNER JOIN jobs as job ON job.id = p.job_id
```

Comment: Yes but what criteria should i put there is no direct connection between the tables i know that the INNER JOIN is the problem, the positions table is the middle table

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are joining the two subquery tables with no clause (ON field1 = field2).

You are pulling the id from the first table and the other fields from the second, with no connecting clause between the table. That is why you are getting partially duplicated data.

You need to add the joining clause between the tables.

I am not going to assume that you can do so logically by joining on the job_id, as was previously suggested.  This would require that the two tables share specific job_ids.  Of course, if this is true, then you just add the ON tab1.job_id = tab2.job_id and you should not see the same duplicated data.

You did not provide the data from the other tables, so I cannot tell if you would still get duplicates, as it would depend on if the same job_id appears in the tables more than once.  To clear that up, you can do a DISTINCT or GROUP BY on all the fields to make the results unique.  The fact that you said you tried distinct seems to confirm that you need the joining clause.

If you cannot join by job_id as it does not logically link the two tables, you will need to provide more logic into what you think the data should look like.